# Why the Set-ADUser Command not allow to use String with number chars?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, attributes

hey i have a problem in my powershell script but i dont know why :/ I think my code is right.

**here is my code:**

```
Set-ADUser –Identity $usr -add @{"extensionattribute1"="test"} # this work

Set-ADUser –Identity $usr -add @{"extensionattribute1"="test2"} # this not!
```

Why I can not input a string with a number char in string but if i use only chars without number chars it works O.o

**Here is my Error: (German)**

Set-ADUser : Für ein Attribut, das nur einen Wert enthalten kann, wurden mehrere Werte angegeben

**Here in English:**

For one attribute, that have only one value,try to input more values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `-add` you can only add the value to an empty attribute.

Once the attribute has been populated, you need to use `-replace` instead of `-add` like so:

```
Set-ADUser –Identity $usr -replace @{"extensionattribute1"="test2"}
```

Or use `-clear` to remove the value before using `-add` again

```
Set-ADUser –Identity $usr -clear "extensionattribute1"
Set-ADUser –Identity $usr -add @{"extensionattribute1"="test2"}
```